# Pandas replace values based on contain match

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Trying to replace '-' value from csv file. with 'no user name' (should be contains match) but getting error

```py
pv = pd.read_csv(Path4 + '\\Profile.csv', index_col=0)
pv.loc[df['User Name'].str.contains('-'), 'User Name'] = 'No User Name'
```

```
error: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Comment: It seems typo not `df` by `pv` like  `pv.loc[pv['User Name'].str.contains('-'), 'User Name'] = 'No User Name'`

Comment: @jezrael Thanks, that was the mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pv = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range('2019-12-01', periods=5),
    'User Name': ['-', 'Daniel', 'Tom', 'Khan', '-'],
    'number': np.random.randn(5)
})
pv

pv.loc[pv['User Name'].str.contains('-'), 'User Name'] = 'No User Name'
pv
```

`df` should be `pv`.